# Where should I begin developing for the Mac?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, macos

I've developed a couple of iOS applications, and apart from that I have no experience developing for the Mac. I'm aware that the Mac developer program has just introduced the Mac app store, so I'm guessing that building a Mac app is now similar to developing an iOS app.

My question is...

Should I start off with the current version of Xcode (without paying for the developer program) and developing my app using the current method... or pay for the program and use the potentially easier method?

Forgive me if I've made some wrong assumptions.

Comment: Related: [Cocoa and Objective-C resources?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571/cocoa-and-objective-c-resources)

Comment: Quite simply -- it is NOT easier. OSX development is exactly the same as it ever was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't heard anything to indicate that there will be an easier method.  The Mac app store is just a new way to distribute a Mac app.  Go ahead and get started with Xcode.  There's no hurry to join the developer program unless you're close to having an app you want to sell.

Comment: Agreed. Just develop and worry about distribution when you're closer to ready to distribute. We've been developing Mac apps for decades without an app store. I don't expect the development process to radically change. Just keep an eye on it as it develops and see if it interests you vs the many other options for the various pieces in the market. Apple is asking 30%; eSellerate takes 6%. Apple gives you more (replacing Sparkle for instance), but you'll need to decide if it's worth it. But it should have little impact on your initial development work.